Odoo 15 Blank Screen: 404 Error on service-worker.js
I'm experiencing a blank screen in Odoo 15 and noticed a 404 error for service-worker.js in the logs:
2024-07-22 13:13:20,539 19686 INFO odoo_15 werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Jul/2024 13:13:20] "GET /web/service-worker.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 17 0.017 0.123
2024-07-22 13:13:24,010 19686 WARNING odoo_15 odoo.http: 404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. 
2024-07-22 13:13:24,015 19686 INFO odoo_15 werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Jul/2024 13:13:24] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 404 - 2 0.001 0.007
2024-07-22 13:13:38,010 19686 WARNING odoo_15 odoo.http: 404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. 
2024-07-22 13:13:38,012 19686 INFO odoo_15 werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Jul/2024 13:13:38] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 404 - 2 0.001 0.003
2024-07-22 13:13:51,502 19686 INFO odoo_15 werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Jul/2024 13:13:51] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 - 2 0.001 0.003
2024-07-22 13:13:51,986 19686 INFO odoo_15 werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Jul/2024 13:13:51] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 - 2 0.001 0.003
2024-07-22 13:14:09,017 19686 INFO odoo_15 werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Jul/2024 13:14:09] "GET /web/service-worker.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 2 0.001 0.003
2024-07-22 13:14:19,224 19686 INFO odoo_15 odoo.addons.base.models.ir_cron: Starting job `Launch server actions execution`. 
2024-07-22 13:14:19,228 19686 ERROR odoo_15 odoo.addons.base.models.ir_cron: Call from cron Launch server actions execution for server action #626 failed in Job #28 

i've remake the whole odoo project new folders new venv but always the same problem .
Looking for insights into fixing the blank screen.

Error 404 is not found.  Usually it means an http request was made to a route the the client credentials do not have access to the Route.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Make sure you gave the correct permission to Odoo's files and folders. Also, make sure the addons paths are correct.
